# How to prevent generation of .csproj.user?

Tags: visual-studio, csproj-user

Certain user specific configurations are stored in .csproj.user.  How do I tell MS Visual Studio to store this information in the .csproj every time?

Comment: Why? What's the problem with having a `csproj.user` file? It allows different settings per user.

Comment: I want all the things that Visual Studio thinks is "user specific" to be belong to the project for every one. Example is the post-build events and output directory for a dll.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and the only solution I could come up with was to manually edit the `.csproj.user` file, cut the configuration I wanted and paste in the `.csproj` file. It worked fine, despite being a somewhat user-hostile solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  Visual Studio stores the user-specific settings in the `.csproj.user` file, and the build settings in the `.csproj` file.  This is to allow multiple users to work on a project, which is critical when working in a team with source control.

That being said, you can always delete the `.user` file, and it will be recreated, at any point in time.

Comment: Just to add to Reed's point: since the `.csproj.user` file is user-specific it should **not** be put under source control.

Comment: My concern is I already have a rule to ignore *.user file, but still it is pushing the .csproj.user file to my source control? Any Idea?

Comment: @Aarush was it already added? if so, you'll have to explicitly remove it, or it keeps looking for changed versions.

Comment: Thanks @ReedCopsey It worked as suggested by you. The file should first be deleted from the remote and then the rule .user works fine (provided already defined in gitignore file)